# SQL substraction

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
Teams (Name, Team ID, Max Size)
Members (Name, Team ID)
```

I need to figure out out how many slots are available on each team.  The closest I got was counting occurrences in `Name` and grouping by `Team ID` in the `Members` table, but after that I have no idea how to subtract `Max Size` by the count_of_Name.  I understand this is a rudimentary question, but I assure you I have been working and researching this question for well over an hour.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

No subqueries needed:

```
select t.[Team ID], t.Name, t.MaxSize - COUNT(m.*) as SpotsLeft
from Teams t
left join Members m on m.[Team ID] = t.[Team ID]
group by t.[Team ID], t.Name, t.MaxSize
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this with a subquery :

```
select (select max(count(*)) 
          from teams 
          join members using(teamId)
          group by teamId) - count(members.*) as available_slots
from teams
join members using(teamId);
```

Note that it would be a lot easier if the maximum possible member per teams would be fixed as you could directly substract instead of using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.MaxSize - (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                      FROM Members m
                     WHERE m.team_id = t.team_id)
  FROM Teams t
```

Or, to avoid (multiple) sub-queries

```
SELECT t.MaxSize, q.Team_Count
  FROM Teams t
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT m.Team_ID, COUNT(*) as Team_Count 
               FROM Members m 
              GROUP BY m.Team_ID) as q
    ON q.Team_ID = t.Team_ID
```